# Fullcalendar scheduler ajax start and dates issue

Tags: ajax, fullcalendar

Hi i have problem with FullCalendar Scheduler because when sending an ajax request with start and end date

```
/myfeed.php?start=2013-12-01&end=2014-01-12&_=1386054751381
```

I don't get events which start on 2013-12-01 but end +1/+2 days later.

Does FC have any option for this problem?

Comment: Can you show the code for myfeed.php?

Comment: Presumably your PHP is not handling this correctly. But since you haven't shared the code, no-one can be certain. Also this sentence "i dont get events witch starts 2013-12-01 but ends +1/+2 days late" doesn't entirely make sense. You don't get events which start 2013-12-01. That's the first issue, a problem with the _start_ date. So when _do_ they start? "but end +1/+2 days later" seems to be a separate issue, a problem with the _end_ date. The second part of your sentence does not follow on from the first. Can you clarify?